# References to case objects with trait usage

Tags: scala, object, traits

I've encountered something which I don't quite understand, so lets begin:

If i've got this object:

```
  case object StartMessage
```

written like above and then obtain its references from two different classes:

```
class Test2 {
  def print(){
    println(Integer.toHexString(System.identityHashCode(StartMessage)))
  }
}


class Test1 {
  def print(){
    println(Integer.toHexString(System.identityHashCode(StartMessage)))
  }
}
```

as expected result is:

```
object ActorMain extends App{
  new Test1().print()//45c8e616
  new Test2().print()//45c8e616
}
```

But when i change case object to pack it in trait:

```
trait model{
  case object StartMessage
}
```

then my classes will have declaration like:

```
class Test1 extends model{
class Test2 extends model{
```

I receive:

```
45c8e616
7d417077
```

*1. Could you explain it to me? I was thinking that objects are one in whole application, so when i create Trait with objects in it, every time i will extends (use "with") those trait, the object will be the same, not somewhat trait scoped.

*2. Is there another way to obtain functionality to "add" same objects only with extending trait to concrete classes, and not make them visible for whole application? Case is to have cleaner code with possibility to "mark" classes as "they use those objects, while others don't"

Comment: Objects aren't singletons for the application, but rather within their declared scope.  Most examples use `object` in the package scope, which is effectively scoped to the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects defined within trait are singletons given trait scope. It is actually referring to the instance of a trait, not the trait itself. And the resulting behavior is the one that you see -> objects are created per instance. And this leads to the conclusion that you cannot define objects by extending traits to be shared across different classes. There was similar question on SO some time ago, I'll try to find it later.

Personally I would go for passing to classes some sort of a context to provide shared resources.